# How do I get parts of my GitLab CI Job Log to fold when viewed on the GUI?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have several GitLab CI Jobs which take a while to run.  I already use the before_script and after_script features to break some of the work into sections.  I would like to add further collapsible log sections within the Job output if that is possible.

[image: Example of Collapsible Job Output as provided by GitLab]

The job sections I can view presently on the GitLab web-interface include timings for each of the collapsible sections shown (see above image).  If I could get more granular timings for each of the new sections created that would be a nice bonus but it is not essential.

I am currently using GitLab Community Edition 12.6.4

---

I tried looking through the [GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Configuration Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) but I could not find and notes on defining your own sub-sections within the log output.  I found an issue requesting a [Collapsible Job Log](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/14664) which does include some suggesting workarounds for adding it but as that issue is closed I thought there was perhaps a more official way than messing with the DOM.  I would prefer to go with an answer of "it is not supported" then make a rob for my own back by doing anything too strange with the output that might break in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Were you looking for something like this?

```
- echo -e "section_start:`date +%s`:my_first_section\r\e[0KHeader of the 1st collapsible section"
- echo 'this line should be hidden when collapsed'
- echo -e "section_end:`date +%s`:my_first_section\r\e[0K"
```

as seen here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#custom-collapsible-sections

Answer (score 5):

Not only can you define addition collapsible log sections, but with [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#pre-collapse-sections-in-the-job-logs) (October 2020), said sections can be collapsed by default.

> ### Pre-collapse sections in the job logs
>
> Job logs often contain very long sections that make it difficult to parse when you are scanning the logs to find a specific piece of information.
>
> Now you can set job log sections to be collapsed by default. To make parsing much easier, simply add `[collapsed=true]` to your job scripts in your CI/CD configuration file as needed.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#pre-collapse-sections) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/198413).

The original link is broken (still works, but links to the wrong page). Instead, look at [Pre-collapse sections](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#pre-collapse-sections)

> Add `[collapsed=true]` after the section name and before the `\r`. The section end marker remains unchanged:
>
> - Section start marker with `[collapsed=true]`: `\e[0Ksection_start:UNIX_TIMESTAMP:SECTION_NAME[collapsed=true]\r\e[0K + TEXT_OF_SECTION_HEADER`
> - Section end marker: `\e[0Ksection_end:UNIX_TIMESTAMP:SECTION_NAME\r\e[0K`